# Error in adding Assembly asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly, dllimport

I am trying to add an Assembly **'obout_Window_NET.dll'** keept in `bin` folder of my asp.net web application, but get this **Compilation error**

> The type or namespace name 'window' does not exist in the namespace 'OboutInc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My **Default.aspx code** is as follows

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="owd" Namespace="OboutInc.window" 
 Assembly="obout_Window_NET" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Any one please give the suggestion to me

Answer (score 0):

In adding assembly, I have just used **Namespace="OboutInc.window"** here I should use **Namespace="OboutInc.Window"** 'W' in capital letter.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="owd" Namespace="OboutInc.Window" 
Assembly="obout_Window_NET" %>
```